# how to call a private class variable form an other private class in C#

Tags: c#, class, variables, call, private

there is my code how to i call the variable startX from underneath private class

if any possible way on C# to call a private class variable from an other private class

it may be a simple question but i am a beginner

can you help me

```
    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        moving = true;
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;

        panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        label1.Text = "" + e.X + "";
        label2.Text = "" + e.Y + "";
        int startX = e.X;
        int startY = e.Y;

    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        moving = false;
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
        panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        int downy = e.X;
        label3.Text = "" + downy + "";
        string one = "1";

        //how to call int startX on this class




        if (label1.Text == label3.Text || label2.Text == label4.Text)
        {
            button1.Text = "The number is : " + one + "";
        }
        else
        { button1.Text = "The number can't calculat"; }
    }
```

Comment: hey, I think you're mixing functions with classes. They are functions and not classes. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

panel1_MouseDown is not a class, it is a private method and you don't call variables, you call methods. If you need to use the value of startX in the panel1_MouseUp method, you can give your panel1_MouseDown method a return value or you make a global variable to store the value. Since your method is called by a mouse event, I would suggest a global variable.

```
private int lastStartX = 0;

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    moving = true;
    x = e.X;
    y = e.Y;

    panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
    label1.Text = "" + e.X + "";
    label2.Text = "" + e.Y + "";
    int startX = lastStartX = e.X;
    int startY = e.Y;

}

private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    moving = false;
    x = -1;
    y = -1;
    panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    int downy = e.X;
    label3.Text = "" + downy + "";
    string one = "1";

    //how to call int startX on this class
    //do whatever you want with lastStartX


    if (label1.Text == label3.Text || label2.Text == label4.Text)
    {
        button1.Text = "The number is : " + one + "";
    }
    else
    { button1.Text = "The number can't calculat"; }
}
```

Comment: so nice it is working. thank you for help me. i was done it. it is grate to me

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, you can't.

Some documentation regarding local functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions.

You would create a variable within the class and not within the function.

```
public class Class
{
    private int startX;
    private int startY;

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.startX = e.X;
        this.startY = e.Y;
    }
    
    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // call this.startX or this.startY
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you i will try its new for me i don't know about class on c# i thing function and classes are same on C# thank you for your information i will try